# Sorting arraylist with mergesort vs custom sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist

I am writing a program which has to be able to sort up to 1 billion random `Squares`. I wrote a small example program below that creates a random `ArrayList` of `Squares` and then sorts it with two different methods.

When I was looking for an efficient method of sorting I found that using a `Merge Sort` was meant to be the most efficient/quickest. However, when comparing a merge sort to a custom sort (don't know if this sort of sort has a name) which I wrote I found the sort I wrote was more efficient.

The output I got from my program was

> Time in nanoseconds for comparator sort: 2346757466
>
> Time in nanoseconds for merge sort: 24156585699
>
> Standard Sort is faster

So why is the sort I wrote so much quicker than a merge sort?
Can either of the used sorts be improved to make a faster, more efficient sort?

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;

public class SortSquares {
    public void run() {
        ArrayList<Square> list = new ArrayList<Square>();
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        int randSize = 10;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++)
            list.add(new Square(i + rand.nextInt(randSize), i + rand.nextInt(randSize)));

        //Create shallow copies to allow for timing
        ArrayList<Square> comp = new ArrayList<Square>(list);
        ArrayList<Square> merge = new ArrayList<Square>(list);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        comp.sort(new SquareSort());
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println("Time in nanoseconds for comparator sort: " + duration);

        long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
        merge = mergeSort(merge);
        long endTime1 = System.nanoTime();
        long duration1 = (endTime1 - startTime1);
        System.out.println("Time in nanoseconds for merge sort: " + duration1);

        if(duration < duration1)
            System.out.println("Standard Sort is faster");
        else if(duration == duration1)
            System.out.println("The sorts are the same");
        else
            System.out.println("Merge Sort is faster");
    }

    private class SquareSort implements Comparator<Square> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Square s1, Square s2) {
            if(s1.getLocation()[0] > s2.getLocation()[0]) {
                return 1;
            } else if(s1.getLocation()[0] == s2.getLocation()[0]) {
                if(s1.getLocation()[1] > s2.getLocation()[1]) {
                    return 1;
                } else if(s1.getLocation()[1] == s2.getLocation()[1]) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Square> mergeSort(ArrayList<Square> whole) {
        ArrayList<Square> left = new ArrayList<Square>();
        ArrayList<Square> right = new ArrayList<Square>();
        int center;

        if (whole.size() <= 1) {    
            return whole;
        } else {
            center = whole.size()/2;

            for (int i = 0; i < center; i++) {
                left.add(whole.get(i));
            }

            for (int i = center; i < whole.size(); i++) {
                right.add(whole.get(i));
            }

            left  = mergeSort(left);
            right = mergeSort(right);

            merge(left, right, whole);
        }
        return whole;
    }

    private void merge(ArrayList<Square> left, ArrayList<Square> right, ArrayList<Square> whole) {
        int leftIndex = 0;
        int rightIndex = 0;
        int wholeIndex = 0;

        while (leftIndex < left.size() && rightIndex < right.size()) {
            if ((left.get(leftIndex).compareTo(right.get(rightIndex))) < 0) {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, left.get(leftIndex));
                leftIndex++;
            } else {
                whole.set(wholeIndex, right.get(rightIndex));
                rightIndex++;
            }
            wholeIndex++;
        }

        ArrayList<Square> rest;
        int restIndex;
        if (leftIndex >= left.size()) {
            rest = right;
            restIndex = rightIndex;
        } else {
            rest = left;
            restIndex = leftIndex;
        }

        for (int i = restIndex; i < rest.size(); i++) {
            whole.set(wholeIndex, rest.get(i));
            wholeIndex++;
        }
    }

    private class Square {
        private int[] location = new int[2];

        public Square(int x, int y) {
            location[0] = x;
            location[1] = y;
        }

        public int[] getLocation() {
            return location;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if(obj instanceof Square)
                if(getLocation()[0] == ((Square) obj).getLocation()[0] && 
                        getLocation()[1] == ((Square) obj).getLocation()[1])
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(getLocation()[0], getLocation()[1]);    
        }

        public int compareTo(Square arg0) {
            if(getLocation()[0] > arg0.getLocation()[0]) {
                return 1;
            } else if(getLocation()[0] == arg0.getLocation()[0]) {
                if(getLocation()[1] > arg0.getLocation()[1]) {
                    return 1;
                } else if(getLocation()[1] == arg0.getLocation()[1]) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortSquares e = new SortSquares();
        e.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get this question. "Why is library algorythm better performing than my implementation" seems self-explanatory. The other way round would be a cause for confusion

Comment: @Deltharis I apologise for any confusion but the `Standard` sort is one I wrote and I have no idea if it has a name or not and the other sort is a merge sort. I don't believe either come in the Java library as I wrote it to sort a custom class into Lexicographical order

Comment: umm... your code shows that "standard" sort is just ArrayList.sort with your own comparator. Library sort algorythm that needed to be told how to actually compare elements. Merge sort on the other hand is your own (or copied from somewhere) implementation. Library sort is faster.

Comment: @Dan I think it's _TimSort_ in the latest implementations of the JRE.

Comment: @Deltharis Ah okay. Thank you for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite is true: the standard method is much faster.

First, you create two arrays in each call to the recursive function mergeSort. The standard one probably merges the elements inplace in the original array, and use indices to the begin and the end of a range.

Second, the standard method can start new threads on multicore machines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.util.Collections.sort( List list ) method from jdk. As mentioned above it uses merge sort with complexity O(nlogn).

In order to measure the performance of your implementation and compared it against other implementation I would suggest to use jmh http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/. Please find below a short example.

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.Options;
import org.openjdk.jmh.runner.options.OptionsBuilder;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@BenchmarkMode( Mode.AverageTime )
@OutputTimeUnit( TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS )
@State( Scope.Benchmark )
@Warmup( iterations = 5)
@Measurement( iterations = 5 )
@Fork( value = 1)
public class SortingPerformanceBenchmark
{
    private final int[] dataArray = new int[10_000_000];
    List<Integer> arrayList;

    @Setup
    public void load() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
           dataArray[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }
   }

   @Benchmark
    public List<Integer> Benchmark_SortObjects() {
             arrayList = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( dataArray ) );
             Collections.sort( arrayList );

          return arrayList;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
       Options opts = new OptionsBuilder()
        .include(SortingPerformanceBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
        .build();
    new Runner( opts).run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering algorithms It depends largely on the data.

Supposedly your sort method is quicksort.
You have O(n2) worst-case runtime and O(nlogn) average case runtime.

Mergesort is always O(n log n). This means stability. That's why it was chosen for sorting for the java collections.

Both sort and the mergesort you implemented is the same algorithm (sort on java collections is based on merge sort). You need to run the same code many times and warm up your jvm first to have more reliable results.
Somehow you can ensure that your custom mergesort is efficient and make comparisons with the collections one.

In any case you don't have to implement you own merge sort for something simple.